# Terraform : Data source retrieves only from one source

Tags: terraform, datasource, terraform0.12+

I have a Network Load Balancer resource ->

```
resource "network_load_balancer_network_load_balancer" "nlb" {
count = 2
  .
  .
}
```

and a data source for the same ->

```
data "network_load_balancer_network_load_balancer" "nlb" {
  depends_on               = [network_load_balancer_network_load_balancer.nlb]
  count                    = 2
  network_load_balancer_id = oci_network_load_balancer_network_load_balancer.nlb[count.index].id

}

locals {
  nlb_ip_addresses = [for nlb in data.oci_network_load_balancer_network_load_balancer.nlb: nlb.ip_addresses[0].ip_address ]
}
```

Now, currently I have one NLB already in my environment, so by the count 2 , it should create another NLB that is being planned in this terraform config.

Environment - 1 NLB

Current Plan- 1 NLB

In this scenario , on `terraform plan` , `datasource` is returning only 1 resource , and local variable `nlb_ip_addresses` has only one element in it and not 2.

Is this expected behaviour ? Is the approach right ? Does data source not consider the resource being planned in the current terraform config ?

There has been same usage of data source in the code currently (without count - ie. only single nlb) and it had been working fine , so just wondering where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Why would you use data source if you already have `oci_network_load_balancer_network_load_balancer.nlb`?

Comment: I'm little new to terraform , please suggest in case when we need existing NLB in the environment not deleted and created again ? to get it's details ?

Comment: The resources have all the details you require. You generally only need data sources to reference data about things not managed in terraform or managed in another state. So really it is just extra api calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing NLB which you want to "add" to TF you have to [import](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import) it so that it can be managed by TF.

Data sources are not used for that. `import` operation is independent from them.

Comment: If we import , will it be a part of list of resources that terraform has in plan ? Currenlty for example 2 , so after import , 1 will be existing and 1 new ?

Comment: @devcodes Yes. Both will be part of TF and you can use TF to fully manage the imported NLB.